# using session echo to welcome userid but echo numbers instead

Tags: php

After logging in, I am trying to display a welcome banner that says welcome userid, however it is displaying welcome 1540102764 instead. Not sure what went wrong. I am guessing my `login.php` did not store the `$_SESSION['login_user']` correctly, either that or I was supposed to use `$_SESSION['login_user']` to retrieve the userid to display the welcome userid.

homepage.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if( !isset( $_SESSION['login_user'] ) || time() - $_SESSION['login_time'] > 1800) {
session_unset();
session_destroy(); 
header("Location:login.php");
} else {
$_SESSION['login_user'] = time(); 
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Homepage</title>
</head>

<header id="header">
<li>Welcome 
    <?php 
    echo 'Welcome ' . $_SESSION['login_user'];
    ?>
</li>

</header>
<footer id="footer">
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include("global.php");
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['login_user'])) { 
header("Location: homepage_admin.php"); 
}

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$conn = new mysqli(server, dbuser, dbpw, db);

$userid = $_POST['txtLogin'];
$password = $_POST['txtPassword'];

$query = "SELECT userid, activeness from users where userid ='$userid' and password = '$password'";
$result = $conn->query($query);

if (! $result){
throw new My_Db_Exception('Database error: ' . mysqli_error());
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if ($row["activeness"] == 0) {
    echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>";
    echo "alert('This account in deactivated.');";
    echo "</script>";
}
else {
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $row['userid'];
$_SESSION['login_time'] = time();
header("location: homepage_admin.php");
};
};
};
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>

<script src="scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>


<body>
<form role="form" action="login.php" method='post'>
<fieldset>
<div>
<label for="userid" ></label>
User ID <input type="text" name="txtLogin" id="txtLogin" placeholder="enter user ID" value="admin" required> 
</div>  
<br/>
<div>
<label for="password"></label>
Password  <input type="password" name="txtPassword"  id="txtPassword" placeholder="enter password" value="admin" required>      
</div>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="btnLogin"  id="btnLogin" value="Login"> <br/>
<input type="reset" name="btnReset"  id="btnReset" value="Reset">
</fieldset>
</form>
<footer id="footer">
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but you replace user with the time?`$_SESSION['login_user'] = time(); `

Comment: Change `$_SESSION['login_user'] = time();`  to `$_SESSION['login_time'] = time();`

Comment: @ErnaniAzevedo I would have thought `$_SESSION['login_time']` should stay as the time they logged in and not when they go to the home page.

Comment: @NigelRen this variable store the last time user was seen, and check at start of page if this time is now - 1800 seconds (30 minutes). If timed out, destroy the session.

Comment: @ErnaniAzevedo, sorry - you are correct, although I've updated my answer also adding a comment to say it should be renamed as it is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your display part, your overwriting the login_user with `time()`...

```
if( !isset( $_SESSION['login_user'] ) || time() - $_SESSION['login_time'] > 1800) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy(); 
    header("Location:login.php");
} else {
   $_SESSION['login_time'] = time();
}
```

As  Ernani Azevedo pointed out, it should be updating `login_time`,  although I would rename `login_time` to something like `last_seen` to be clearer.

Comment: It is now working but sadly it is displaying 'welcome 1' when my intended result is something along the lines of 'welcome admin', depending which user logged in...

Comment: Is the `userid` column on the database the name or just the ID, you may want to change the SELECT in your login page to fetch a different column.